# Не пингуется сервер на hyper-v из debian на wsl

Tags: debian, lan, ping, hyper-v, wsl2

Проблема такая. Есть hyper-v с Win Server и есть wsl с Debian. При попытке пингануть win с debian он соображает что такое есть, но ответа от винды не приходит. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в с настройках virtual switch в Hyper-V Manager.
По умолчанию и WSL и Default switch имеют тип Internal и оба находятся за NAT.
Создайте external virtual switch и перенесите туда виртуальную машину - она будет в той же сети, что и физическая машина, но будет доступна из WSL.

Answer (score 0):

Ip по умолчанию в wsl выдает по какому-то критерию, очень отличный от виртуальной сети. Поменял в сетевых подключениях vEthernet (WSL) ip и все взлетело как надо.

Comment: Нет, не работает. Каждый раз получает автоматом новый IP.